# Find distance between two points

Tags: matlab, graph

Essentially, I have a list of points that I know are all connected upwards, downwards, leftwards, rightwards, or diagonally. Given two points, I want to find the minimum number of points you would have to travel to get to the other point.

Comment: Have you tried any specific solution?

Comment: [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is VERY popular.

Answer (score 0):

Update: ended up going with an A* (A star) algorithm

Link to matlab code of A star algorithm that I used: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56877-a-astar-a-star-search-algorithm-easy-to-use